# Drupal 6 Registration Password Field Missing

Tags: drupal-6

I have taken over support for a Drupal site, and need to change the registration process so that users enter their password when registering, rather than receiving an email with a system generated password.  This should be as simple as un-checking the "Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account" check box, however, the password field does not appear.  Unfortunately, the person who set up the site originally is not available.

I've checked the various modules we have to see if one of them is the cause, I've checked our theme/stylesheet, and confirmed that we did not change the user.module at all.  I've tried installing LoginTobaggan.

I do know that Drupal knows that the box is not checked, as it sends out the email for no email verification required.

Any ideas on what could prevent the password field from appearing or other places I could check?

Answer (score 0):

```
example.com/admin/user/settings

uncheck:
Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the root of my problem.  I have unchecked that option, and I know it has worked as it sends the correct email when registering, but it does not display the password field.

Comment: Then you may need to look into user permissions... If not, since you took over this site,  you may have to run some tests on a local copy, making sure that every component of the site is clean.